# ImageShack API and Python

Tags: python, api, imageshack

I wanted to start programming my first simple application just for learning purpose but I've encountered some problems - ImageShack API. For program that I want to create this API would help a lot but I'm using Python language and I don't know really will it work or no? I'm beginner on programming so I still don't know many things. Maybe language for programming doesn't matter? Help please.

Ignas.

Comment: Also, how far are you in the process of programming? Have you set up Python already? If not, I'd recommend taking a look here: http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/set-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Python has a lot of wonderful libraries that make it highly utile for this type of application. I would say in general that most languages can do most things, but languages do have their strong point, and due to built in libraries and other available add-ins Python is very strong for web interfaces, etc. in addition to being easy to learn.

Also, there is lot of information available about how to interface Python with website based solutions, here are a few places to get you started:

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

[Web Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming)

[Imageshack.py](http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2007/09/15/imageshackpy/)